# getting file path from command line argument in python with an argument -i

Tags: python

python3 test1.py -i /home/server/Desktop/json1.json

Can anyone guide me how can I get file path if we pass file from command line argument
I need to specify -i in command line with the path

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Look up ```argparse``` module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `argparse` module to take arguments as input to the program:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My program inputs')

# -i is argument name, dest is where it will be saved inside the parsed arguments Namespace
parser.add_argument('-i', dest='file_path', help = 'Path to input file')

args = parser.parse_args()

print('File path: ', args.file_path)
```

Now, run the code file: `python3 test1.py -i /home/server/Desktop/json1.json`